# Angularjs table sometimes shows sometimes it doesn't

Tags: angularjs

I am facing an issue where an angularjs data table displays properly but fails to do so after a refresh of the view. Sometimes I can refresh the view 2-10 times without a problem and other times all it takes is one refresh for it to not display completely.

Here is the code that controls that specific part of the view:

```
                         <div ng-show="selectedSubmissionTab_Upload.batchProcessStatistics[0].batchStatus.statusDescription == 'Failure' && selectedSubmission_Upload">
                            <h5 style="top: 35px; display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 100%; color: #1965A8; padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px; font-weight: bold;">Submission Issues
                                <label style="float: right; color:#d9534f; display: inline-block;">Total Errors
                                    <span>{{selectedSummaryItem.batchMessages.length}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </h5>
                            <div>
                                <table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover agsTable" style="width: 100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="tableHead">
                                            <th>
                                                Row
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Column
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Message
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="item in selectedSummaryItem.batchMessages" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                                            <td>{{item.dataRow}}</td>
                                            <td>{{item.dataColumn}}</td>
                                            <td>{{item.message}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="downloadBatchErrors()" style="position:relative; top: -40px;">Download Error List</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And the js code that interacts with it:

```
      function getSubmissionSummary(calPk, companyPk) {
        HomeFactory.getSubmissionSummary(calPk, companyPk)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.submissionSummaryList = response.data;
                console.log('Summary response: ' + $scope.submissionSummaryList);
                for(i=0;i<$scope.submissionSummaryList.length;i++){
                    if($scope.selectedTaskSubmissionPk == $scope.submissionSummaryList[i].submissionPk){
                        $scope.selectedSummaryItem = $scope.submissionSummaryList[i];
                        console.log('Assigning: '+$scope.selectedTaskSubmissionPk +' to '+$scope.submissionSummaryList[i].submissionPk);
                        console.log('Selected submission summary item: '+$scope.selectedSummaryItem.numRows);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                if (error.status == 401) {
                    window.location.href = $scope.baseUrl;
                }
            })
    }
```

The console logging was me trying to see if the correct values are being assigned and I can confirm that they are.

When the table loads it looks like this:

[Table has successfully loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ04U.png)

When it fails to load the table it looks like this:

[Table failed to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jam0o.png)

As you can see from the second image, the array that is meant to be loaded on the table is recognized but the table itself doesn't show. Help and advice towards resolving this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

when table is not loaded what is your console window showing? any error ?

Comment: The console shows no error, just a bunch of messages I use for debugging in the User messages and messages section.

Comment: can you provide demo url?

Comment: Due to the nature of the project, I'm unable to provide a demo url. It's a snippet of a fairly huge one.